# How pass parameter in hight order suspend function with invoke

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I want call hight order suspend function from other class with parameter and i don't know how.

```
class CharactersListViewModel : ViewModel() {

private val dataSourceFactory =
    PageKeyDataSourceFactory(
        scope = viewModelScope,
        request = suspend {createRequest(0)
        }
    )
private suspend inline fun createRequest(offset : Int): MutableList<CharacterItem> {
    val repository = Injection.provideMarvelRepository()
    val response = repository.getCharacters(
        offset = offset,
        limit = PAGE_MAX_ELEMENTS
    )
    return CharacterItemMapper().map(response).toMutableList()
}
```

other class

```
class PageKeyDataSourceFactory<Value>(
    private val scope: CoroutineScope,
    private var request: suspend () -> MutableList<Value>
) : DataSource.Factory<Int, Value>() {
private var dataSource: PageKeyDataSource<Value>? = null

override fun create(): DataSource<Int, Value> {
    dataSource = PageKeyDataSource(request = request, scope)
    sourceLiveData.postValue(dataSource)
    return dataSource as PageKeyDataSource<Value>
}
```

and class here i call function

in loadAfter function comes a params that I want to be used to call request.invoke()

```
class PageKeyDataSource<Value>(
    private val request: suspend() -> MutableList<Value>,
    private val scope: CoroutineScope,
) : PageKeyedDataSource<Int, Value>() {

    override fun loadAfter(params: LoadParams<Int>, callback: LoadCallback<Int, Value>) {
        scope.launch(
            CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, _ ->
                retry = {
                    loadAfter(params, callback)
                }
                networkState.postValue(NetworkState.Error(true))
            }
        ) {
            val data = request.invoke()
            callback.onResult(data, params.key + PAGE_MAX_ELEMENTS)
            networkState.postValue(NetworkState.Success(true, data.isEmpty()))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class PageKeyDataSource<Value>(private val request: suspend (yourParams:YourType) -> MutableList<Value>) {
   ...
   // some code

   val list:MutableList<Value> = request.invoke(yourParams)
}
```

Comment: thx for asnwer, but request come to from consctructor and func is suspend

Comment: how can I write this here?     PageKeyDataSourceFactory(
        scope = viewModelScope,
        request = suspend {createRequest(0)
        }
    )

Comment: ure answer is half the question, other half is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67053418/how-pass-parameter-in-hight-order-suspend-function-with-invoke